# Find out MNC, MCC

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, cellid

Kia Ora friends, I know there have been a couple of topics about it, but I am still confused about the following:
I want to check out MNC and MCC on iPhone, using Swift 4 on iOS 11.1.
My code is the following:

```
var mob = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
if let r = mob.subscriberCellularProvider { //creates CTCarrierObject
  print(r.mobileCountryCode!)
  print(r.mobileNetworkCode!)
}
```

At the moment, I am just getting the following error:

> Could not successfully update network info during initialization.

I am just using it in iPhone Simulator, I haven't been testing it on a real phone yet.

So does anyone know, what I need to change? And is it just an error because the Xcode Simulator cannot simulate that or will I get the same error on real devices as well? Thank you!

Comment: You need to test on a real phone. How can you get cellular network info from a device that doesn't have a cellular network subscription (the simulator)?

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right. I thought it is a simulator, because it's able to simulate that as well.

Comment: Do you know, how to determinate LAC and/or CellID with the same framework and my code above? I found a couple of topics about it, but nothing for swift, as of the fact that I don't understand objective-c.