# Is it possible to determine the location of the user from sim card details?

Tags: ios, geolocation, gps

Tiktok privacy policy says that TikTok can also determine its users' location through sim card info even if the GPS service is turned off. So, I just want to know how it's possible and how they are doing it? I am writing an app for iPhone which requires users' locations to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an iPhone dev, but the MCC ([Mobile Country Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_country_code)) can be returned from the network operator. It won't give you a precise location (it's country level), but it doesn't require GPS.

Another similar question on this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49094236/find-out-mnc-mcc). Hopefully this will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

TikTok privacy policy really allows App to read Sim data.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vA4pt.jpg)

There are a few parameters on Sim Card chip that Tiktok is interested in and based on that I can determine user "home"  country. So country that sim card was issued (sim card home network country).

Basically MMC + MNC tell Tiktok What country was sim card issued and what is its home network. 
Here is he full list:
https://tik.cards/mobile-country-code-and-mobile-network-code-list/

Below is the example of card i use (this one is from [Tik.cards](https://tik.cards/)) for Japan.. You see it uses MMC 440 and MNC 10, and its "home" conutry is Japan.
[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WANh2.jpg)